# Frank cucumber can't access the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, ios-simulator, frank

I'm learning about automated iOS testing methods and right now I'm trying Frank. I've written small simple app and added Frank to it. The problem is - I can't get it to work at all. I've gone through the tutorials and various "Getting started" guides - everything seems to be OK, I've run

> frank setup

Goes fine. All the folders and stuff are created

> frank build

OK. "Frankified" build appears.

> frank launch

It launches the simulator with the app open. But I can't do anything else.

> frank inspect

Opens *localhost:37265* with "could not connect" message. When I run

> cucumber

Starts the simulator, begin to run features, but the first one, device rotation gets PING FAILED!!! message:

> Feature:    As an iOS developer
> I want to have a sample feature file
>
> So I can see what my next step is in the wonderful world of
> Frank/Cucumber testing
>
> Scenario:                                             #
> features/my_first.feature:6
>
> ```
>   Rotating the simulator for demonstration purposes
> ```
>
> PING FAILED!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I've checked and re-checked accessibility, re-installed Frank. Tried to add it to new, empty app - all the same. It can launch it, but it can't do anything else.

Using xcode 5, iOS7 and OS X 10.8.4

I can't find what I'm missing here

Comment: Try running the frankified app from Xcode and check the console output for Frank debug lines. As it looks like a test app, you can upload it somewhere and let us know where.

Comment: You can also see the logs for your app in Console.app without the need to run it with Xcode. You can also enable additional logging information. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/frank-discuss/Logging/frank-discuss/TB0gsQX2NXg/eiLxtmyGs-0J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution (in more old tutorials). I don't know why official tutorial doesn't contain these steps, but it didn't work without them for me.

1. Run **"frank setup"** inside project folder in the console to create Frank folder with all the stuff needed
2. In your xCode project, create new target. It's necessary , because we'll add some frameworks which are not needed in you distribution version.
3. Add all *.a files from Frank folder to your new frank target (obviously, if you making an app for iOS, you don't need libraries for Mac. It's easy to identify them by "Mac" word in the name)
   [image: Frameworks]
4. Add **"-all_load"** and **"-ObjC"** flags to "Other linker flags" in you xCode project "Build settings"
   [image: Build settings]
5. Run **"frank build --target [your_target_name]"** inside project folder in the console
6. Run **"frank launch" + "frank inspect"** You should go to *localhost:37265* where Symbiote will display your app
7. Go to "Frank" folder inside your project, run **"cucumber"** to launch tests

If you want to debug fankified app through xCode, you must go to "Manage schemes" and select proper executable for you frank target.

[image: Scheme preferences]

Than you can launch frankified app with tests just as usual one (Cmd+R) and see all the debug lines inside xCode console

Comment: This should not be necessary. Frank setup is supposed to perform these steps for you. Did you run frank setup in the same directory as your xcodeproj file?

Comment: As I understood it from different articles - in past, you'd had to do these by yourself, but now it's all automated. Nevertheless, until I'd done those steps manually - nothing worked.